Corefile with 64K segments and a section
I have a corefile that was generated, that contains 0xffff segments, and has a section.   Almost all of these segments are single page blocks assigned to [heap].  I have no clue why it is generating these, but my real question is why does a corefile house a section?
I have the following elf header (arm-64 little-endian):
7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
----------- -- -- -- ----- --------------------

04 00 b7 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
^^a^^ ----- ----------- -----------------------

40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 76 4e 01 00 00 00
----------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^b^^^^^^^^^^^^

00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00 ff ff 40 00 01 00 00 00
----------- ----- ----- ^^c^^ ----- ^^d^^ -----

Where the parts underlined with ^ show that a) it is indeed a corefile, b) there is a populated section offset, c) there are 64k segments, and d) there is a section.
It makes sense to me that if a core cannot house all segments, it might create a section, and store all additional information in there, but I'm not finding any references to this online.    I'm wondering if anyone knows if this is indeed expected behavior.   (Also, if anyone has any insight about why each page of a heap might constitute a different segment in a coredump, that would also be helpful).
